# Jersey: Entity Data Filtering and inherited fields

Tags: java, reflection, jersey, moxy

The chapter on Entity Data Filtering in the Jersey manual shows code that looks like this at example [17.17](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.modules.custom)

```
@Inject
private Provider<ObjectProvider<ObjectGraph>> provider;

@Override
protected void preWriteTo(final Object object, final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations,
                          final MediaType mediaType, final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
                          final Marshaller marshaller) throws JAXBException {
    super.preWriteTo(object, type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, marshaller);

    // Entity Filtering.
    if (marshaller.getProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH) == null) {
        final Object objectGraph = provider.get().getFilteringObject(genericType, true, annotations);

        if (objectGraph != null) {
            marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, objectGraph);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run a near equivalent of this code and look at the contents of the `objectGraph`, I see that inherited fields are not present.  That is, say the `genericType` above looks like this:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    private String baz;
    private Foo foo;  // Some non-primitive type.
    // ...
}
```

and `Parent` looks like this:

```
public abstract class Parent {
   private int bar;
   // ...
}
```

If I call `objectGraph.getFields()` within `preWriteTo()` above, I'll see the `baz` field in `Child` but not `bar` from `Parent`.  Likewise, if I loop through the contents of `objectGraph.getSubgraphs()` I'll see `foo` from `Child`, but no non-primitive types from `Parent`.  Note that `bar` and other fields from `Parent` are correctly marshalled into the JSON output (using MOXy in this case), so we know JAXB is working.

Is the lack of access to inherited fields intentional?  I would like to examine the fields in parent class(es) while within this logic, and perform manual conversion of a Jersey `ObjectGraph` to a MOXy equivalent, but either include or remove fields as specified by the caller.  I cannot do this if I cannot access every field that is included in the output.

Note that I'm using Jersey 2.4 and MOXy 2.5.1.

Comment: Please, file an improvement into our JIRA - https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY. I think we can support entity hierarchy but few questions, i.e. whether entity-filtering scopes should be inherited or overridden in child classes, have to be answered (lets move the discussion into the JIRA issue).

Comment: Done: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2255

Answer (score 0):

Check Java reflection api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html
and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html
to get all information you need from `objectGraph.getEntityClass()`

Comment: This isn't really _just_ a reflection issue, as what we're looking at here are the JAXB names for the fields and methods (I didn't list methods in my post, but they are present).  So the question is why Jersey isn't letting me see the JAXB names on the inherited classes even though it knows they are there and MOXy will process them correctly.  I _could_ do all the JAXB-style reflection myself, but that's going to be messy and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a pull request for a fix for this, currently waiting for my OCA to clear.  Hopefully it's in the 2.7 release...

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/68